# Whats the best (fastest) way to scape webpages?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape data from Google Patents and finding the execution time takes too long. How can I increase the speed? Running through 8000 patents took 7 hours already...

[Here](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6403086B1/en?oq=US6403086B1)'s an example of a patent.

I need to get data from the tables below and write them to a csv file. I think the bottle neck is at `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='table style-scope patent-result']")))`

Is this necessary or can I use *find_elements_by_css_selector* and check if that returns anything?

```
#...
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
#...

##  read file of patent numbers and initiate chrome

url = "https://patents.google.com/patent/US6403086B1/en?oq=US6403086B1"

for x in patent_number:

    #url = new url with new patent number similar to above

    try: 
        driver.get(url) 
        driver.set_page_load_timeout(20) 
    except: 
        #--write to csv
        continue

    if "404" in driver.title: #patent number not found
        #--write to csv
        continue

    try: 
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='table style-scope patent-result']"))
        )
    except: 
        #--write to csv
        continue


    ##  rest of code to get data from tables and write to csv
```

Is there a more efficient way of finding if these tables exist on a patent page? Or would there be a difference if I used BeautifulSoup?

I'm new to webscraping, so any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are you after two tables? Patent Citations and Non Patent citations? All tables on page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure which tables you are after but consider you may be able to use requests and pandas to grab the tables, as well as Session to re-use connection.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

codes = ['US6403086B1','US6403086B1'] #patent numbers to come from file
with requests.Session() as s:
    for code in codes:
        url = 'https://patents.google.com/patent/{}/en?oq={}'.format(code, code)
        r = s.get(url)
        tables = pd.read_html(str(r.content))
        print(tables)  #example only. Remove later
       #here would add some tidying up to tables e.g. dropNa rows, replace NaN with '' .... 
       # rather than print... whatever steps to store info you want until write out
```

Comment: I'd like to get data from all tables. I'm trying to understand the difference between BeautifulSoup and Selenium. What advantage does BeautifulSoup have over selenium in this use case? When would I use one over the other?

Comment: selenium allows you to automate a browser... javascript can render on the page in cases where content is dynamically loaded, you can interact with site controls e.g. buttons etc. Requests is much faster but you lose the ability to interact with a webpage as there is no browser. Also, javascript loaded content won't be present. In your case, requests is faster. The response object content is then parsed with BeautifulSoup and lxml.

Comment: the above answer will print all tables. You can decide what you do with them. Each table us returned as a dataframe inside the returned list.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to grab the titles of the tables as well? For example, I need "Patent Citations (1)" that comes before the table. I want to use these titles to determine where to store certain table data.